# How can you partially fill an array in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on trying to partially fill an array, however when running, the program continues to run past the limit that was given by the user. Is there another way to partially fill an array?

The initial NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLUMNS constants are placeholders until the program work

```
#include <iostream> // Input and output
#include <iomanip> // Input manipulator
#include <array>
using namespace std;

// Number used to initialize an array
const int NUM_ROWS = 10;
const int NUM_COLS = 10;

int userFilledArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

int row; // Amount of rows the user will fill
int col; // Amount of columns the user will fill

int main()
{
   
    int num; // Number that is placed in a specific row and column
    
    int total; // Total of every integer in the array
    int average; // Average of every integer in the array
    int rowTotal; // Total of every integer in a specific row
    int colTotal; // Total of every integer in a specific column
    int highestInRow;
    int lowestInRow;
    
    
    // Asks the user to enter the number of rows they would like to fill
    cout << "How many rows in the array would you like to fill? (Between 1 - 10)" << endl;
    cin >> row;
    
    // Asks the user to enter a number between 1-10 if the user enters a character or integers not between 1-10
    while (row < 0 || row > 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1-10" << endl;
        cin >> row;
    }
    
    // Asks the user to enter the number of columns they would like to fill
    cout << "How many columns in the array would you like to fill? (Between 1 - 10)" << endl;
    cin >> col;
    
    // Asks the user to enter a number between 1-10 if the user enters a character or integers not between 0-10
    while (col < 0 || col > 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1-10" << endl;
        cin >> col;
    }
    
    // Now the user will fill the array with as many numbers needed
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) // WARNING!!! NOT WORKING
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < col; j++) // WARNING!!! NOT WORKING
        {
            cout << "Enter a number for row " << i << " and column " << j << endl;
            cin >> num;
            userFilledArray[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
    
    total = getTotal(userFilledArray);
    cout << total << endl;
        
}
```

This is the area that is not working properly

```
 // Now the user will fill the array with as many numbers needed
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) // WARNING!!! NOT WORKING
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < col; j++) // WARNING!!! NOT WORKING
        {
            cout << "Enter a number for row " << i << " and column " << j << endl;
            cin >> num;
            userFilledArray[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You're allowing the user to fill `0` rows? What does that mean? ... I think that you want the user to enter a number of rows from 1 to 10, and translate that into a range of row indices to set, from 0 to 9. That should put you on the right track?

Comment: `for(int j = 0; i < col; j++)` spot the typo

Comment: Style note: you could rewrite your loops like this:`do{ cout << "How many columns in the array would you like to fill? (1 - 10)\n"; cin >> col;} while (col < 1 || col > 10);` and save some redundant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problematic line:

```
    for (int j = 0; i < col; j++) // WARNING!!! NOT WORKING
```

And it also demonstrates why single-letter variable names lead to bugs. You cut and pasted this from the previous for-loop, and you didn't change every instance of variable `i`.